# Query for joined tables. Long & skinny to short & fat

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables tblCompany and tblContact that are joined on CompanyID

I need a query that lists all of the tblContact.ContactPhone for all tblContact.contacts where tblCompany.CompanyID =tblContact.CompanyID all on one row per CompanyID

So, rather than having the ComanyID in the first column and the ContactPone in the second with multiple rows for each Company (long & skinny) the end result will be one row for each tblCOmpany.CompanyID with all of the tblContact.ContactPhone in columns to the right (short & fat)

Is this even possible?

[image: tblCompany]

[image: tblContact] 
[image: Desired Result (short and fat)] 
[image: Example of long and skinny (to illustrate what I mean by long and skinny)]

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please show your source tables (with sample data), how you would like the sample data to appear after the desired query, and any query you have been trying along with the full text of any error messages it produces.  Please show some indication of the research that you have done into this matter.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask a Good Question.

Comment: Need a field with a sequential ID for each company group. This can be done in a query using DCount(). Then build CROSSTAB query with the first query. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536461/pivoting-a-table-with-predefined-headers/43537359#43537359. Otherwise, review http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html